# Problema ao exibir a maior e a menor nota

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" id="entrada" placeholder="Nome">
   <input type="button" value = "Iniciar"onclick = "botao()">

   <input type="text" id="entrada2" placeholder="nota">
 <ul id="tabela">
     <li id="NotaMaior"></li>
     <li id="NotaMenor"></li>
 </ul>
   <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**javaScript**

```
"use strict"
let maior = 0
let menor = 0
function botao() {
    tabela.innerHTML +=
        `<tr>
             <td> ${entrada.value} </td>
             <td> ${entrada2.value}</td>
         </tr>`
    if (entrada2.value > maior) {
        maior = entrada2.value
    }
    else if ((entrada2.value < menor) || (menor == 0)) {
        menor = entrada2.value
    }
    NotaMaior.innerHTML += ` / Maior ${maior}`
    NotaMenor.innerHTML += ` / Menor ${menor}`
}
```

Estou com problema na hora de mostrar o maior e o menor, poderiam me ajudar ? Grato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é um problema de tipagem e está acontecendo porque a propriedade `value` do JavaScript te retorna uma `string`. Você não terá problemas quando executar o código pela primeira vez, porque irá comparar `string` com um `number`. Porém, ele salvará seu resultado (maior) como `string` e aí que está o problema. Quando você tentar comparar duas `string` ele sempre comparará apenas o primeiro digito de ambas `string`. Para corrigir o problema basta transformar sua `string` em um `number`.

Comment: Solucionou um dos meus problemas, mas agora estou com mais um problema. 
adicionei a seguinte linha no meu código
```javascript
if(Number(maior) < Number(menor)){
menor = maior
}
```
O menor só pega um valor menor que o 3, se logo depois do 3 eu digitar por exemplo 1.
Ficando assim :
maior : 1 // maior : 2 // maior : 3 // maior : 3 
menor : 0 // menor : 0 // menor : 0 // menor: 1
Gostaria que se eu digitar 1,2,3 ..o menor fosse pegando os menores resultados e mostrando na tela.
Ficando dessa forma : 
maior : 1 // maior : 2 // maior : 3 ..
menor : 0 // menor : 1 // menor: 1 ..